# Fetch data in order to edit on form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created this table:

```
Settings
-----------
id (PK)
name
value (default: NULL)
catogory // not sure if I actually will need it
```

and inserted some data, eg:

```
1, description, NULL, meta
2, keywords, NULL, meta
3, color, NULL, shirts
4, size, NULL, shirts
```

What I want to do for example is to fetch on my page all data that belong in **meta** category, so that I can edit the value collumn. So basicly my form will have to look like this:

```
<form>
    <input value=" (the value if keywords here) ">
    <textarea>(the value if description here)</textarea>
</form>
```

then on another page to edit the settings for **shirts** category etc etc.

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM (`settings`) WHERE `category` =  'meta' ORDER BY `id`
```

but I cant figure out how to put each value on the specific field, without looping the data

Comment: You will need to loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as you want, but if you tell us what exactly you're trying to do, there could be a better method.

```
<?php 
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM (`settings`) WHERE `category` =  'meta' ORDER BY `id`");
?>
<form>
<?php 
while($array=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
      if($array['name']=='keywords'){ ?>
          <input value="<?php echo stripslashes($array['name']);?>">
      <?php } elseif($array['name']=='description'){ ?>
          <textarea><?php echo stripslashes($array['value']);?></textarea>
      <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
</form>
```

Comment: whouldn't this loop always repeat the the form tags ??

Comment: @Lykos That's the best part, it wont.

Comment: it will only repeat the `input` and `textarea` for each row you have in the database table that has category=meta

Comment: ok, how can I make sure that the input will take the value of 'keywords' and the textarea the value of 'description'??

Comment: ah now I understood what you want, 1 min will update the code